# Uppercase the first character of each word in a string except 'and', 'to', etc

Tags: php

How can I make upper-case the first character of each word in a string accept a couple of words which I don't want to transform them, like - and, to, etc?

For instance, I want this - `ucwords('art and design')` to output the string below,

'Art and Design'

is it possible to be like - `strip_tags($text, '<p><a>')` which we allow

and  in the string?

or I should use something else? please advise!

thanks.

Comment: You mean "except", right? You wouldn't necessarily want to use a blanket exclusion because those words can begin sentences.

Comment: sorry yes i meant "except" lol

Answer (score 22, accepted):

None of these are *really* UTF8 friendly, so here's one that works flawlessly (so far)

```
function titleCase($string, $delimiters = array(" ", "-", ".", "'", "O'", "Mc"), $exceptions = array("and", "to", "of", "das", "dos", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI"))
{
    /*
     * Exceptions in lower case are words you don't want converted
     * Exceptions all in upper case are any words you don't want converted to title case
     *   but should be converted to upper case, e.g.:
     *   king henry viii or king henry Viii should be King Henry VIII
     */
    $string = mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
    foreach ($delimiters as $dlnr => $delimiter) {
        $words = explode($delimiter, $string);
        $newwords = array();
        foreach ($words as $wordnr => $word) {
            if (in_array(mb_strtoupper($word, "UTF-8"), $exceptions)) {
                // check exceptions list for any words that should be in upper case
                $word = mb_strtoupper($word, "UTF-8");
            } elseif (in_array(mb_strtolower($word, "UTF-8"), $exceptions)) {
                // check exceptions list for any words that should be in upper case
                $word = mb_strtolower($word, "UTF-8");
            } elseif (!in_array($word, $exceptions)) {
                // convert to uppercase (non-utf8 only)
                $word = ucfirst($word);
            }
            array_push($newwords, $word);
        }
        $string = join($delimiter, $newwords);
   }//foreach
   return $string;
}
```

Usage:

```
$s = 'SÃO JOÃO DOS SANTOS';
$v = titleCase($s); // 'São João dos Santos'
```

Comment: How can I modify this so that letters directly after numbers are lowercase (e.g., "32ND" becomes "32nd" not "32Nd")?

Comment: slight improvement : replace the `ucfirst` call by `if(count($word) > 0) $word = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($word, 0, 1, "UTF-8"), "UTF-8") . mb_substr($word, 1, null, "UTF-8");` so that it can capitalize names that start with an accent as well.

Answer (score 7):

since we all love regexps, an alternative, that also works with interpunction (unlike the `explode(" ",...)` solution)

```
$newString = preg_replace_callback("/[a-zA-Z]+/",'ucfirst_some',$string);

function ucfirst_some($match)
{
    $exclude = array('and','not');
    if ( in_array(strtolower($match[0]),$exclude) ) return $match[0];
    return ucfirst($match[0]);
}
```

**edit** added `strtolower()`, or "Not" would remain "Not".

Comment: nonsense answer, try this `art\'android and design` **PS** do not assume regex is the only way

Comment: @ajreal: Like he was assuming anything. He clearly stated that it was an "alternative".

Comment: @ajreal: cool down dude. Your suggestion results in "Art'Android and Design" which is intended. There are countless other ways, but regex is a) quick to implement b) easy to follow and c) has little side-effects. And not to forget: d) easy to amend, should you decide to view `'` as a word-character.

Answer (score 7):

How about this ?

```
$string = str_replace(' And ', ' and ', ucwords($string));
```

Comment: str_replace('And', 'and', ucwords($string)); - this works well too. simple and easy to understand! thanks :-)

Comment: @lauthiamkok - but your assumption will fell into trap mentioned by @mvds

Comment: @ajreal, @lauthiamkok: "You're not coding for Android". Trust me, `str_replace` or any other context-insensitive string manipulation will never be a solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: @mvds - see your answer comment

Answer (score 5):

You will have to use ucfirst and loop through every word, checking e.g. an array of exceptions for each one.

Something like the following:

```
$exclude = array('and', 'not');
$words = explode(' ', $string);
foreach($words as $key => $word) {
    if(in_array($word, $exclude)) {
        continue;
    }
    $words[$key] = ucfirst($word);
}
$newString = implode(' ', $words);
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it is a few years after the question, but I was looking for an answer to the insuring proper English in the titles of a CMS I am programming and wrote a light weight function from the ideas on this page so I thought I would share it:

```
function makeTitle($title){
    $str = ucwords($title);     
    $exclude = 'a,an,the,for,and,nor,but,or,yet,so,such,as,at,around,by,after,along,for,from,of,on,to,with,without';        
    $excluded = explode(",",$exclude);
    foreach($excluded as $noCap){$str = str_replace(ucwords($noCap),strtolower($noCap),$str);}      
    return ucfirst($str);
}
```

The excluded list was found at:
http://www.superheronation.com/2011/08/16/words-that-should-not-be-capitalized-in-titles/

```
USAGE: makeTitle($title);
```