# How to not capitalize the "of" & "and" using this approach?

Tags: php

here's my exampl I really want to get how to not capital the "of" & "and" in this.

```
  <?php
     $string = "united states of america";
        $a = strtoupper($string);
        $b = strtolower($string);
        $c = ucfirst($string);
        $d = ucwords($string);
        $e = ucwords(strtolower($string));

    echo $a;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $b;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $c;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $d;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $e;
    echo '<br>';
    ?>
```

result will be:

```
UNITED STATES OF AMERICA
united states of america
United states of america
United States Of America
United States Of America
```

how to do this?

```
United States of America
```

Comment: Well, you could explode the string and then loop through the newly created array and use a if clause to check if the word is "of" or not, if not then Capitalize the word, once done with the loop, simply implode the array back into a single string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uppercase the first character of each word in a string except 'and', 'to', etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580699/uppercase-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string-except-and-to-etc)

Comment: There is no direct approach here, since "the words 'or' and 'and'" is a completely arbitrary definition. So you need some sort of dictionary / word list to decide which words to treat special.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple code

```
$string = "united states of america";
echo $a = str_replace("Of","of",ucwords(strtolower($string)));
```

Comment: I would add some spaces to this: `str_replace(" Of "," of ", ...)` or a bit more sophisticated solution is to use regex (`\bof\b`)